# Проблема с bootstrap-select

Tags: html

При добавлении `bootstrap.min.css` меняется дизайн шаблона, можно что то сделать?

Нормальный вид

[image: При добавление этих файлов[![Нормальный вид сайта]

При добавлении этих файлов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<select id="lunchBegins" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Please select a lunch ...">
    <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
    <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
    <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
    <option>Baby Back Ribs</option>
    <option>A really really long option made to illustrate an issue with the live search in an inline form</option>
</select>
```

Comment: HTML код приложите

Comment: Приложил, скачал другой bootstrap, select и option кривые

Comment: как фрагмент приложите

Comment: не получается, много локальных файлов

Comment: Минимальный пример сделайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve как было до и как после

Comment: Вы добавляете `bootstrap.min.css` после ваших стилей по порядку?

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день, это связано с конфликтом названий ваших классов и классов bootstrap'а. При помощи инструментов разработчика (f12 в браузере) справа можно посмотреть какие свойства css перезаписываются и что идет не так. Без демки сложно сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Переименуйте класс `selectpicker`. это класс bootstrap select, так что если не хотите, что применялся стиль из библиотеки, то имя класса должно быт уникальным.

Comment: Разверните ваш ответ. Поясните, почему именно это требуется сделать и тд.